# CSS Font-size to maintain same word width

Tags: javascript, css, responsive, font-size

I'm trying to get the words "Hello", "Projects", "Social" and "Contact" to responsively adjust their font-size so that the words are all the same width rather than having to go in pixel by pixel.

I thought I was on to something with using viewport width but that isn't having the effect I'm after.

See image for the desired effect.

[image]

Comment: in addtion to font-size you may also consider letter-spacing

Comment: Please the code. Looks like you have a lot of padding and margins.

Comment: Oh you can ignore that Saif. This is just a screen shot of and Adobe XD design. The end result is going to open up like drawers.

Comment: Are you open to using JavaScript?

Comment: @Sol. Definitely. Not an expert by any stretch but yes.

Comment: @TomJardine-Smith I've added the JavaScript tag in your question, and provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You may adjust `font-size` and also `letter-spacing` using `vw` unit

```css
.title {
  font-size: 15vw;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.title:first-child {
  letter-spacing:5vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="title">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Projects
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may end up being the solution I use but I'd rather not rely on letter spacing and change size instead if possible,

Comment: @TomJardine-Smith then you may have different font-sizes and it may no look good

Comment: Fair comment. I'll have a think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to wrap each letter in a span. Then you can use flexbox to distribute the `spans` evenly inside the `p`.

The words in the example below are inside a `div` with a fixed width in `px`. You can use other units as you need - `%`, `vw` etc

**Example**

```js
const words = document.querySelectorAll('.tracking');

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  const text = words[i].textContent.split('');
  words[i].innerHTML = '';

  text.forEach((letter, index) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const textnode = document.createTextNode(letter);
    span.appendChild(textnode);
    words[i].appendChild(span);
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tracking {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
div div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: orange;
}
div div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
div div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p class="tracking">Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="tracking">Projects</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="tracking">Social</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="tracking">Contact</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great. Would this work with my example as the words are spread across multiple divs? (i.e. each colour segment in my OP) I'm also using Bootstrap for structure currently (although I'm thinking about scrapping that and going solo instead as there's now a few things that are breaking it), is that going to be an issue?

Comment: @TomJardine-Smith I've updated the answer. It's probably cleaner to target a class than just `<p>`. It won't matter if it's nested inside a `div`. As to your question about bootstrap, it's probably fine but I couldn't say for sure without seeing your markup.

Comment: I was about to comment and say this still wasn't working but I realised I was using some Bootstrap utilities that were overriding your CSS. It works! Now I just need to find a neat work-around for aligning the text properly instead of using those utilities. Thanks Sol.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = document.getElementById("master");
// set your margin... depends from font style
  var margin= 2;
  function font(){
  var lett = document.getElementById("master").clientWidth;
  

  setInterval(function(){font()},0)}

 function getCount(matchResult) {
  return matchResult ? matchResult.length : 0;
}


function alert(){
var pm = document.getElementById("master").querySelectorAll('*');
  var num ;
  for (num = 0; num < pm.length; num++){
  var str = pm[num].textContent;
var countA = getCount(str.match(/A/g));
var countB = getCount(str.match(/B/g));
var countC = getCount(str.match(/C/g));
var countD = getCount(str.match(/D/g));
var countE = getCount(str.match(/E/g));
var countF = getCount(str.match(/F/g));
var countG = getCount(str.match(/G/g));
var countH = getCount(str.match(/H/g));
var countI = getCount(str.match(/I/g));
var countJ = getCount(str.match(/J/g));
var countK = getCount(str.match(/K/g));
var countL = getCount(str.match(/L/g));
var countM = getCount(str.match(/M/g));
var countN = getCount(str.match(/N/g));
var countO = getCount(str.match(/O/g));
var countP = getCount(str.match(/P/g));
var countQ = getCount(str.match(/Q/g));
var countR = getCount(str.match(/R/g));
var countS = getCount(str.match(/S/g));
var countT = getCount(str.match(/T/g));
var countU = getCount(str.match(/U/g));
var countV = getCount(str.match(/V/g));
var countW = getCount(str.match(/W/g));
var countX = getCount(str.match(/X/g));
var countY = getCount(str.match(/Y/g));
var countZ = getCount(str.match(/Z/g));
var counta = getCount(str.match(/a/g));
var countb = getCount(str.match(/b/g));
var countc = getCount(str.match(/c/g));
var countd = getCount(str.match(/d/g));
var counte = getCount(str.match(/e/g));
var countf = getCount(str.match(/f/g));
var countg = getCount(str.match(/g/g));
var counth = getCount(str.match(/h/g));
var counti = getCount(str.match(/i/g));
var countj = getCount(str.match(/j/g));
var countk = getCount(str.match(/k/g));
var countl = getCount(str.match(/l/g));
var countm = getCount(str.match(/m/g));
var countn = getCount(str.match(/n/g));
var counto = getCount(str.match(/o/g));
var countp = getCount(str.match(/p/g));
var countq = getCount(str.match(/q/g));
var countr = getCount(str.match(/r/g));
var counts = getCount(str.match(/s/g));
var countt = getCount(str.match(/t/g));
var countu = getCount(str.match(/u/g));
var countv = getCount(str.match(/v/g));
var countw = getCount(str.match(/w/g));
var countx = getCount(str.match(/x/g));
var county = getCount(str.match(/y/g));
var countz = getCount(str.match(/z/g));
var countspace = getCount(str.match(/ /g));
var groupa = 22*(counti+countj+countl);
var groupb = 28*(countI+countf+countt);
var groupc = 33*(countr);
var groupd = 50*(countJ+countc+countk+counts+countv+countx+county+countz);
var groupe = 56*(countL+counta+countb+countd+counte+countg+counth+countn+counto+countp+countq+countu);
var groupf = 61*(countF+countT+countZ);
var groupg = 67*(countA+countB+countE+countK+countP+countS+countV+countX+countY);
var grouph = 72*(countC+countD+countH+countN+countR+countU+countw);
var groupi = 78*(countG+countO+countQ);
var groupj = 83*(countM+countm);
var groupk = 94*(countW);
var groupl = 28*(countspace);

var totalsize = (groupa+groupb+groupc+groupd+groupe+groupf+groupg+grouph+groupi+groupj+groupk+groupl)/100;
var lett = pm[num].clientWidth;
var final = Math.floor(lett / totalsize) ;
pm[num].style.fontSize=final-margin+"px";
}
setInterval(function(){alert()},0)
}


window.onload = function(){ 
  
  font();
  alert();

}
```

```css
div {text-align:center;
width:350px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;}
p{
background-color:gray;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
color:white}
.orange{
background-color:orange;}
.red{
background-color:red;}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="master">
 <p>Text using font-master.js </p>
 <p>How simply is that </p>
 <p class="orange">Hello</p>
 <p class="red">Project</p>
</div>

</body>
```

you can use my js. plug in it is easy and free to use:
https://github.com/foxreaper/font-master

Text will fit to your div or sreen size... If you will have any issue let me know.

Comment: This looks like it might be my solution! Thanks Piotr!

Comment: I would assume down voted because it's not an answer to the question.. A plugin doesn't help answer a question, even though it may be a solution to his problem.

Comment: @Piotr, I thought I got it working for a second but it's not. I've got your plugin installed, linked to properly and referenced in the id of the divs wrapping the text but not working currently. Does the fact I'm using Bootstrap in tandem have any baring here? Trying to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: Copy my code from example 2 in my readme and paste it inside your script tag in your html file. It might help

Comment: Hi Piotr, sorry for delay. Had to go back to work. Will try the above now. Thanks.

Comment: Piotr, when your documentation says "Step 5: Set up width of your elements." where is this supposed to take place? Just in css using a relevant class tag or in-line html or in the JS somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174061/discussion-between-piotr-mirosz-and-tom-jardine-smith).